# Manually add to combobox in Datagrid using c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I find the following problem a little bit tricky, and need your help on the matter.

I have a popupbox, containing a datagrid. This datagrid consists of 3 columns, one of those is a combobox.

The datagrids itemssource is bound to a property, which I want to use to extract information entered in the datagrid.

The problem is, that the combobox in the datagrid should be populated dynamically, and preferably not using a binding. So I want to add elements to the combobox using C# in the code-behind.

How can I add items to a combobox, that is part of a datagrid, using c#?

Comment: Why do you not want to use binding?

Comment: I'm actually not gonna do this in the code-behind, it is going to be placed in a command, and the combobox cannot bind to the right property, since its datacontext is somewhere else.. At least from what I get out of it.

Comment: @JesperPlantener you need to use `RelativeSource` to find the DataGrid's ViewModel inside the CellTemplate or something. Don't try to force WPF to the archaic procedural approaches of crappy winforms. you will fail miserably. WPF does not support developers with a winforms mentality.

Comment: @JasperPlantener or else create a "Row ViewModel" for each row, which contains the Collection to be used as the `ItemsSource` for the ComboBox.

Comment: That could probably work. I'm just trying another solution right now, and if that does not work i'll return to that one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Assigning the databinding/itemssource from code did the trick. I had totally forgotten about this option when I wrote the question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into this, hope it helps

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/76ca886f-923b-4696-8cc6-731e5e362683/datagrid-rowunique-combobox?forum=wpf

Comment: -1 Not only because answering with a link to an external resource is inappropiate, but also because that's a really bad solution.